# 2007 Equinox overheating at idle

Tags: overheating, temperature

Flushed coolant system, replaced radiator cap. A Tried Reprogrammed emc , light "turn off engine overheating" , when idiling. Fans keep running after car is off,AC on, no problems when ac off.

Comment: What is the temp gauge showing? Have you rechecked the overflow-expansion tank level after several heat cool cycles? Have you tried any of the burping techniques generally suggested for GM vehicles?

Comment: Does the car overheat with AC off ?

Comment: Flushed and burped the system. Replaced overflow reservoir cap. Only overheats with AC  on while idiling. Leaking water on passenger side occasionally